# Supported hardware for Hokuyo_node

Tags: ros, navigation, laser, hokuyo-node, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do [hokuyo_node](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node) supports [Hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 Scanning Laser](http://www.robotshop.com/en/hokuyo-urg-04lx-ug01-scanning-laser-rangefinder.html), Can i use this node as the driver for the laser scanner?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229216/supported-hardware-for-hokuyo_node/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2016-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it should. You probably can also use [urg_node](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node) which is a bit newer, but likely makes not much of a difference for the LIDAR you use.

See also the [urg_node-vs-hokuyo_node Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/194022/urg_node-vs-hokuyo_node/).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2016-03-16**:
I am just developing a prototype so i don't need more accuracy, a basic steady navigations is enough. Will hokuyo URG satisfy the basic requirements of ROS navigation stack ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-03-19**:
Yes, many robots navigate successfully using this sensor and the ROS navigation stack.